# How to match an underscore using Python's regex?

Tags: python, regex

I'm having trouble matching the underscore character in Python using regular expressions. Just playing around in the shell, I get:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r'a', 'abc')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb746a368>
>>> re.match(r'_', 'ab_c')
>>> re.match(r'[_]', 'ab_c')
>>> re.match(r'\_', 'ab_c')
```

I would have expected at least one of these to return a match object. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `re.match` returns match if it is in starting of string..use `re.search`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that.

Comment: `re.match(r'.*\_.*', string)` ?

Answer (score 6):

Use `re.search` instead of `re.match` if the pattern you are looking for is not at the start of the search string.

> **re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)**
>
> Try to apply the pattern at the start of the string, returning a match
>   object, or None if no match was found.
>
> **re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)**
>
> Scan through string looking for a match to the pattern, returning a
>   match object, or None if no match was found.

You don't need to escape `_` or even use raw string.

```
>>> re.search('_', 'ab_c')
Out[4]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(2, 3), match='_'>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
re.search(r'\_', 'ab_c')
```

You were indeed right to escape the underscore character!
Mind that you can only use match for the beginning of strings, as is also clear from the documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding MatchObject instance. Return None if the string does not match the pattern; note that this is different from a zero-length match.

You should use `search` in this case:

> Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding MatchObject instance. Return None if no position in the string matches the pattern; note that this is different from finding a zero-length match at some point in the string.

Comment: The issue here isn't escaping the underscore: it's that OP is using `match` and they want `search`